# Dynamically create a C structure memory content with proper alignment

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, x86, x86-64

The [C/Invoke](http://cinvoke.nongnu.org/doc/index.html) library contains functions for dynamic calling of C functions and the dynamic creation of C structures on the heap which in turn can be passed to dynamically created stack-frames representing dynamic function calls. While the latter function of that library is exactly what I need, I can't use this library because of the use cases it's intended to satisfy. I think that using this library would result in ugly code. What I need is a set of functions like the following

```c
struct dyn_struct {
  int size;
  int members;
  char *bit_field;
};

int add_member_uint(struct dyn_struct *struct, unsigned int value);
int add_member_int(struct dyn_struct *struct, int value);
int add_member_float(struct dyn_struct *struct, float value);
[...]
int add_member_pvoid(DynStruct *struct; void *value);
```

To be more specific I am using the library `libffi` to dynamically call dynamically loaded C library functions using structures as parameters. I am writing an interpreter for a little programming language (combination of Lua and C, which is probably not very creative...)

Comment: And your question is? Be specific!

Comment: As far as alignment is concerned, you should use `#pragma pack(n)` to add/remove padding.

Comment: Sorry, for not being specific. My question is: Do you know a library that can dynamically build structures in heap memory the way i sketched it.

Answer (score 0):

In not sure I fully understand what you're looking for, but using libffi, if you populate an ffi_type structure describing your type, then ffi_type's size and alignment fields will get populated the first time you call ffi_prep_cif with it.  The static initialize_aggregate() function is responsible for this.  That might be a useful function for us to expose to users.